# CakePHP cannot create/ find action in controller

Tags: cakephp, php

I am having some trouble creating an additional view in CakePhp
From what I understand you need to match the view file name and the controller function.
The function is in the correct controller, but CakePHP still gives me this error:

```
Error: The action userMutualFriends is not defined in controller UserProfileController

Error: Create UserProfileController::userMutualFriends() in file: app\Controller\UserProfileController.php.

<?php
class UserProfileController extends AppController {


    public function userMutualFriends() {

    }

}
```

Though I pasted the exact same function into the controller.
I have no experience with CakePhp, so maybe I am just missing something..

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: Is the controller in the right location i.e. app\Controller\ also just noticed; the CakePHP convention is to have the controller as a plural i.e. UserProfilesController, not sure if that will help here

Comment: It is actually already a fully working controller, with 3 views added to it. The problem is that I don't know how to add my own (I have to finish an application).

Comment: Try setting your debug level to 2

Comment: I am sorry, but how would one do that in CakePHP?

Answer (score 2):

I am the biggest idiot, was using a back-up so changing the wrong files..
Sorry for wasting your time.